# PHP-RegEx for german full name with umlauts and some internationalisation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Dear Stackoverflowianers,
Dear RegEx-Gurus,

I was searching the web for regex pattern that checks the plausibility of a full name in german language. I found many posts on patterns without german umlauts aso... From all this posts and my logical understanding I build this pattern together yet:

```
^([A-ZÖÄÜ]{0,1})([-a-zäöüß\.']{2,30})( {1}|-{1})([A-ZÄÖÜ]{0,1})([a-zäöüß']{0,30})( {1}|-{1})?([A-ZÖÄÜ]{0,1})([a-zäöüß']{0,30})(( {0,1}|-{1})([A-ZÖÄÜ]{0,1})([a-zäöüß']{0,30}))+$
```

It should match the following possible variations (status now)(expected):

- "Hans Spitzer" (match)(yes)
- "hans spitzer" (match)(yes)
- "Hans-peter Österreicher" (match)(yes)
- "Dr. Anna-Marie Pelzer-Hahnenkamp" (match)(yes)
- "Dipl-Ing. Gerhard Meyer" (no-match)(no)
- "Lisa-Maria Brandner-Kapeller" (match)(yes)
- "John Mc'Connor" (match)(yes)
- "John" (no-match)(yes)
- "Johann " (match)(no)
- "Osama Al Sawarri" (match)(yes)
- "Frank F." (no-match)(yes)
- "Johann F. Kerner" (no-match)(yes)
- "Johann F Kerner" (match)(no)
- "li xian" (match)(yes)
- "Li Xian" (no-match)(no)
- "Li Fu" (no-match)(no)
- "li fu" (match)(yes)

(where status now means if it matches now and expected means if it should or should not match)

I need to use this pattern for preg_match in PHP.

I'd be so thankfull if somebody could help me to refine this pattern. As soon it is - nearly - perfect I will add it to http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ for public use (they have 2 or 3 fullname checks but they're not working well or not at all).

Thx. in advance for your help...

Best regards, Ingmar

Comment: What you want is impossible. Generally its impossible for a computer (or even possibly a human being) to say what's a "plausible full name"  and what not - most certainly not just with a regular express. You'd need some serious AI to do that. Also your requirements seem contradictory. Why is "Dr." ok, but not "Dipl.-Ing."? How can "John" be ok, but no "Johann"? Why would "li xian" be ok, but not "Li Xian"?

Comment: Thanx for your reply! Sorry, you missunderstood my syntax of list above: It means NAME(does it match on my expression)(should it match or not)

Comment: My problem is: li xian matches and should match but Li Xian does not match, which should be matched. E.g. John without a empty space before or after does not match (thats ok) but "Johann " (with space after) matches but should not match, because it is not a full name... Do you understand what I mean? It does not have to be 100% perfect, I only want to filter out unwanted data like "hahaha" or "Fu$$y Boy" or just "je".

Comment: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)...

Comment: "Li Fu" (no-match)(no) "li fu" (match)(yes) <---- you expect "li fu" to to match but you expect "Li Fu" to not match?

Comment: I expected/not expected the result in the left brackets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, if someone finds this thread and is looking for the best possible answer, here it is:

(Thanx to all on this thread for good help!)

With this regex pattern:

```
^([^\$%\^*£=~@\d]+){2,30} ([^\$%\^\.*£=~@\d]+){2,30}+$
```

my list from above (original question) looks like this:

Possible variation (status now)(expected):

- "Hans Spitzer" (match)(yes)
- "hans spitzer" (match)(yes)
- "Hans-peter Österreicher" (match)(yes)
- "Dr. Anna-Marie Pelzer-Hahnenkamp" (match)(yes)
- "Dipl-Ing. Gerhard Meyer" (match)(yes)
- "Lisa-Maria Brandner-Kapeller" (match)(yes)
- "John Mc'Connor" (match)(yes)
- "John" (no-match)(yes)
- "Johann " (no-match)(yes)
- "Osama Al Sawarri" (match)(yes)
- "Frank F." (no-match)(yes)
- "Johann F. Kerner" (match)(yes)
- "Johann F Kerner" (match)(no)
- "li xian" (match)(yes)
- "Li Xian" (match)(yes)
- "Li Fu" (match)(yes)
- "li fu" (match)(yes)

(Explaination: E.g. "li fu" (match)(yes) means, the name "li fu" matches and "yes" it is expected so)

Thanx again to all, this pattern is exactly what I was after.

Best regards,

"Ingmar Erdös" (match)(yes)

PS: This pattern works perfect in ecma (javascript) based regex operations but seams not to work in prce based operations like preg_match in PHP. 
Does anybody have an idea how to convert ecma to prce based patterns??? Have searched google up and down but no converter at all is online... 
Please give me some ideas, hints or a solution. Thnx. in advance.

Comment: Simpler and powerful. Thanks Ingmar :)

Answer (score 8):

Given the vast range of perfectly valid names in use around the world, you should do the absolute minimum of validation on it. People with hyphens and apostrphes in their names get rightfully annoyed when they're told that their name is invalid.

Even trying to force initials to have a dot after them may be wrong, as there are plenty of people in the world with single-character names.

My advice would therefore be to not validate it at all.

However if you *must* do some kind of validation, then the best advice I can give is to stick to filtering out symbols that you definitely want to exclude, and avoid doing anything more complex than that.

So a simple pattern might look like this:

```
/[^\$%\^\*£=~@]/
```

That will prevent the user from including symbols like `$` or `@` in their name, because yes, those are pretty implausible for a valid name. But make sure you do allow quote marks and hyphens, commas, and even brackets, because real people do have these characters in their names.

Hope that helps.

Comment: People have brackets in their names? `[]`

Comment: Thank you for your very helpfull answere. Indeed I want the people at least to enter their fullname, which surely consists of at last two parts. Can you please update your pattern to also check for that? (E.g. "José" does not match, "José $tringer" does not match, "José " (empty space after) does not match but "José Stringer" matches well. Thanx in advance.

Comment: ups... and numbers shouldn't match: /[^\$%\^\*£=~@0123456789]/ is that correct? Thanx again.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ - I have heard of people with round brackets `()` in their names. I haven't heard of anyone with square brackets, but I wouldn't say it's out of the question.

Comment: @IngmarErdös - Yes, if you want to exclude numbers as well as symbols, that would do it. You can also put `0-9` or `\d` to shortcut the list of digits.

Comment: @IngmarErdös - Most of the time people have `()` parenthesis in their names it's because they're trying to identify their nickname or a maiden name. It's not necessarily their original or real name. Outside of that difference everything that Spudley's describing is covered by my answer (which also looks for tabs, hard returns, and characters found in HTML tags (which you also don't want in real names)... although if someone named their baby `<html>` I doubt the world would change their acceptance of characters for them.

Comment: Without validation you run into things like SQL injection and XSS attack territory.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ - Validation is not the answer to those issues; proper escaping is the answer. You shouldn't block input that would cause an injection attack, you should escape it. Blocking SQL attack characters would prevent people with apostrophes in their names from entering their names.

Comment: @Spudley I've been doing web security for 20 years and would have to disagree with you. Research some of this stuff before you speak of it as if you know what you're talking about. Assertiveness without substantiation is costly. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#Introduction

Comment: @Spudley Ok, thnx. So if I understand it right: /^([^\$%\^*£=~@\d]+){2,30} ([^\$%\^*£=~@\d]+){2,30}+$/g would do the job forcing the visitor to enter at least a second name with at least two letters and maximum of 30 letters per name and enter as much names as needed. Is that right in your understanding?

Comment: @IngmarErdös - yes, something like that will do it. You can probably drop either the plus sign or the `{2,30}` on each of the character classes, since they both achieve much the same thing.

Comment: @Spudley - please, can you once more give me your helping hand? On gskinner.com/RegExr the pattern works perfect but in php preg_match() function, I'm only able to give two names... if e.g. I enter the name "Wolf Dietmar Eibensteiner", it doesn't match. The pattern I use for it now is: /^(([^\$%\^*£=~@\d]+){2,30}) (([^\$%\^\.*£=~@\d]+){2,30})+/ Thanx. in advance... Br. Ingmar

Comment: put the second block *and the space before* it into brackets with a plus sign at the end. (you already have the brackets and the plus; you just need to include the space inside the brackets)

Comment: Thanx for your sugestion. Do you have any idea why this does not work with preg_match in php? It works perfect on gskinner.com but in php, as soon as I enter a 3 words name, it doesn't match anymore... :( Why regex is not equal to regex...

Comment: regex != regex because regex isn't standardised; it's different across different programming languages. It's mostly similar, but there are differences. I guess the one on gskinner is using the javascript regex engine. I don't know if that's the problem in this case, but it is important to know about. One suggestion might be to switch on the unicode flag; try adding the `u` flag at the end of the expression (ie outside the pattern, like this `/.../u`). This is probably important, since you're dealing with accented characters, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's not practical to try and do this with RegEx alone.

The best way I've found to do this sort of thing is to take the reverse approach. Rather than doing something like a dictionary attack on potential names (which is possible using census and birth records), you might take a look at patterns of names (in this case German names) on the whole and look for things that you can use to identify things that are definitely not names. You would have to take into account Germanized names from other countries for the instances involving people who have moved to Germany.

Things that would NOT be names contain:

- a number character
- a mathematical operator other than a hyphen
- slashes, double-quotes, and other non-expected name
  characters (&^%*$#)
- newline and paragraph characters
- tab characters

**Code:**

```
<?php
    $score = '0';

    $notInNames = "![0-9!@#$%^&*()_+={}|\\\\;\"\n\r\t\[\]<>?/]!";

    if(!preg_match($notInNames,$potentialName)){
       //It could be a real name
    } else {
      $score = $score+10;
    }

    if(preg_match('!(^[.-]|[.-]$)!',$potentialName)){
      $score = $score+10;
    }

    if(!preg_match('! !',$potentialName)){
    // no spaces in the name, give them a +1
      $score++;
    }

    if($score > 5){
        //not a name.

    }

?>
```

Then if you want to take it a bit further, you can look at the average consonant to vowel ratio for German names and then build ranges of tolerance for acceptable names.

```
$vowels = "![AaEeIiOoUuäöüÖÄÜ]!";

$stripped_pn = preg_replace('! !','',$potential_name);

$length_sans_spaces = strlen($stripped_pn);
$withoutVowels = strlen(preg_replace($vowels,'',$stripped_pn));
$VowelsOnly = $length_sans_spaces - $withoutVowels;

//Consonant to Vowel Ratio
$ratio = $withoutVowels/$VowelsOnly;
```

Comment: Thanx all for your help, I will try to combine all your recommendations and try to build the best possible filter. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after your comment, it's a bit clearer what you want. But it is still not really possible. What about other characters? Take, for example, "André Rieu", "Bernhard Hoëcker" or your namesake "Paul Erdős".

And if you want to allow single names, then its impossible to forbid "hahaha".

Instead of cramming everything into one regular expression. What you could do are some simple tests:

- Is there are at least one space (unless you want to allow single names, and there are places where people only have one name)
- Is the first letter uppercase (use for example [\p{Lu}](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php))
- Does it contain any "forbidden" characters, such as "$"
- etc.